# How to test IAB without being charged

Tags: android, testing, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I am trying to testIn App Purshase without being charged on Unity by reading this https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

My application is published as an Alpha version, signed with a real key. I downloaded it with an other Google account that the one I used to publish the app. This account is both added in the testers list of Google Play Service and my app Alpha testers list.

The problem is, when I want to buy an item, I never see the word "test" as the documentation says.

Can someone explain to me which extra steps shall I do in order to be sure to test my In App Billing without being charged?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would like to add that I tried to pay, and it actually charged me some money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the [Testing In-app Purchases](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html):

**Setting up test purchases**

> It’s easy to set up test purchases—any user account can be chosen to
>   be a test account, and any user of a test account can make test
>   purchases with any available payment method (even though there’s no
>   charge to the payment method).
>
> First, upload and publish in-app products that you want testers to be
>   able to purchase. You can upload and publish in-app products in the
>   Developer Console. Note that you can upload and publish your in-app
>   items before you publish the APK itself.
>
> Next, create license test accounts for authorized users. In the
>   Developer Console, go to Settings > Account details, then in the
>   License Testing section, add the addresses to Gmail accounts with
>   testing access field. For more information, see Setting Up for Test
>   Purchases.
>
> Once you’ve added the users as license tester accounts and saved the
>   change, within 15 minutes those users can begin making test purchases
>   of your in-app products.

Comment: A new version of Google Play Console was released the17th April, and I think that the documentation was not refreshed.
So I don't have the License Testing section as the documentation says.
I also want to precise that I have the french version of the Google Play Console, maybe the License Testing section is only available in english.

Answer (score 1):

A new version of Google Play Console was released the 17th April, and I think that the french version of the Google Play Console was not completely implemented.

Right now the section "Test de licence" is available.